# Converting a video to flv format by using ffmpeg is working in local but not working in server

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to convert a video to flv format. I am using ffmpeg to convert the video. I am using following code.

```
exec("C:/wamp/www/newtip/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i C:/wamp/www/newtip/ffmpeg/videos/".$name." -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 C:/wamp/www/newtip/ffmpeg/players/".$name_s.".flv");
```

It is working correctly in the local system. But in the server it is not working correctly.

In the server i changed the code as below

```
exec("http://www.mydomain.com/newtip/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i http://www.mydomain.com/newtip/ffmpeg/videos/".$name." -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 http://www.mydomain.com/newtip/ffmpeg/players/".$name_s.".flv");
```

In local I have given the Source path as C:/wamp/www/newtip/ But in server i have given the path as http://www.mydomain.com/newtip/ .I think in the server the path is wrong. Can anybody tell me how to give the path in the server?

Comment: I am having the ffmpeg detected, but i cant give my site on wamp permission to access it. How do i do it? please help. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777374/ffmpeg-permission-in-windows-wamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify the correct directory and also specify the document root with:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "your required folder path here";
```

Make sure that:

- Folder has required permissions set, chmod to 755
- `exec` is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing paths and urls. In place of `http://www.mydomain.com/newtip/ffmpeg/ffmpeg`, use the full path (something like... `/home/username/mydomain.com/newtip/ffmpeg/ffmpeg`).  As Sarfraz recommends, you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to find the root for your path.

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` runs on PHP which runs on the server, so use the path as if you're truly running it on the server with the local paths.

Answer (score 0):

i had **exact** the same problem, it turned out to be the codec.

`-acodec mp3` is working on local but the server required `-acodec libmp3lame`